# What is a "global script file" in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

> hello-world.ts(4,1): error TS1208: 'hello-world.ts' cannot be compiled under '--
> isolatedModules' because it is considered a global
> script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement
> to make it a module.

I hadn't added the export keyword in front of the function. That was the reason of this error.

Here I want to understand the "meaning" of this error message.
It mentions "global script file".
What does that mean?

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#isolatedModules, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#how-javascript-modules-are-defined

Comment: @jonrsharpe thak you for the links.